# Pass some arguments with link and detect it while loading link page using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Process :

1. Send Email to particular user and mail body contains unique link.
2. At the same time I need to store that unique link in database across that user.
3. As User clicks the link from his mail body I need to open one web page and at the loading time I need to validate that link whether it is the same link for that user.
4. If Yes, load page with reset password form, otherwise show some message of invalidation.

In the above process I just want a code for sending user_id and unique code with link and detect it at the time of loading link page in ASP.net c#.

I used `GUID` for creating unique link and sends the mail successfully. While loading link page I am unable to validate user.
Here Is my code :

```
 protected void btnRECOVER_PASSWORD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendMail();
        }

        public void SendMail()
        {

            login = new NetworkCredential("leaves@nworks.co", "password");
            client = new SmtpClient("smtp.1and1.com");
            client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(25);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Credentials = login;            
            msg = new MailMessage { From = new MailAddress("leaves@nworks.co", "nWorks Employee", Encoding.UTF8) };
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("dipak.akhade@nworks.co"));
            msg.Subject = "Recover Password For Your nWorks Leave Management Account";
            msg.CC.Add(new MailAddress("dipak.a.akhade9192@gmail.com"));
            //       msg.CC.Add(new MailAddress("*************user mail id*************"));
            string strBody = string.Empty; 
            Guid code = Guid.NewGuid();

                strBody += "<html><head></head><body><p>Click the following link to recover your password.</p>";
                strBody += Environment.NewLine;


                strBody += "<form action='' method='POST' name='myForm1'><a href='http://localhost:19343/LoginForm.aspx'>'" + code.ToString() + "'</form><br>";



            strBody += "<br/>Thanks.</body></html>";

            msg.Body = strBody;

            msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            msg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
            msg.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
            client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
            string userstate = "sending.......";
            client.SendAsync(msg, userstate);

            string q1 = "insert into RecoverPwdStatus values(101,'" + code.ToString() + "');";
            MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(q1, conn); conn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader rdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader(); conn.Close();

        }
```

Comment: I used GUID for creating unique link and sends the mail successfully. While loading link page I am unable to validate user.

Comment: Can't you just send an email address as a parameter?

Comment: But I have to make that link one time use so i will put it in database across the user and remove when user clicks the link. If user clicks same link next time I will check if that link is present in database i will allow him to reset password otherwise will show You have reset password using same link. User will not able use one link for resetting password more than one time.

Comment: For that purpose we need to identify user and link too.

Comment: please show some code.

Comment: just ask your question clearly with the code you worked with..

Comment: @DipakAkhade, create the email link such as this http://localhost:19343/LoginForm.aspx?usercode=code.ToString(). in the loginform read the parameter passed using Request.QueryString["usercode"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following for creation of link :

```
<a href='http://localhost:19343/ResetPasswordForm.aspx?guid="+code.ToString()+"&userid="+getUser()+"'>
```

Access these parameter while loading link page and do whatever with them you want...

```
 string v = Request.QueryString["guid"];
            string v1 = Request.QueryString["userid"];
```